# Providing multiple sort options by implementing Comparable in inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, comparable, compareto

I have an array list of person objects, each with a first name, last name and age. I would like to use an inner class to provide a way to sort these objects by first name.

How would I access the overridden compareTo method inside the inner class? I would like to use inner classes because once sort by first name is working, I will create inner classes to sort by the other attributes.

```
package listdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

        people.add(new Person("Homer", "Simpson", 29));
        people.add(new Person("Mo", "Sizlak", 23));
        people.add(new Person("Bart", "Simpson", 22));
        people.add(new Person("Peter", "Griffin", 30));
        people.add(new Person("Joe", "Swanson", 27));

    }
}
```

```
package listdemo;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;

        //create an instance of the inner class upon initialization of Person
        Person.CompareFirstName compareFirstName = this.new CompareFirstName();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " +  this.age;
    }

    class CompareFirstName implements Comparable<Person> {

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person comparePerson) {
            System.out.println("inner class compareTo method invoked");
            int difference = Person.this.firstName.compareTo(comparePerson.getFirstName());
            return difference;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class compareFirstName

```
class compareFirstName implements Comparator<Person>{
@override
public int compareTo(Person p1,Person p2){
return p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
}
}
```

on your main method create on instance of above class and use Collections class to sort

```
compareFirstName c = new compareFirstName ();
List<Person> yourPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
.........................
Collections.sort(yourPersonList, c);
for(Person p : yourPersonList) {
  System.out.println(p.getFirstName()+","+p.getLastName()+","+p.getAge());
}
```